# W/DynamiteModule(23516): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

When I debug my app on my MotoG8 Turbo. My app automatically logins with the last logged in credentials. It gives out an error which does not come on normal login. Error is mentioned in end. Even if I make apk of it on first start it logins with last credentials.
It is running a login function on LoginPage() which is triggered on sign-in button press. but it is running automatically.

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Themes _theme = new Themes();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
    return MaterialApp(
      builder: (context, child) {
        return ScrollConfiguration(
          behavior: MyBehavior(),
          child: child,
        );
      },
      home: handlemainscreen(),
      theme: _theme.currentTheme,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

Widget handlemainscreen() {
  return StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
    builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
      Constants.allocateSize(size: MediaQuery.of(context).size);
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Scaffold(body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
      }
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return HomePage(snapshot.data);
      } else {
        return LoginPage();
      }
    },
  );
}
```

Error that comes up

```
W/DynamiteModule(23516): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule(23516): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(23516): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/xample.monktre(23516): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
W/xample.monktre(23516): Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (light greylist, reflection)
I/xample.monktre(23516): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/xample.monktre(23516): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
V/NativeCrypto(23516): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 286 native methods...
W/xample.monktre(23516): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (light greylist, reflection)
D/NetworkSecurityConfig(23516): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/ProviderInstaller(23516): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
W/xample.monktre(23516): Accessing hidden field Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl; (light greylist, reflection)
W/xample.monktre(23516): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (light greylist, linking)
W/xample.monktre(23516): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (light greylist, linking)
W/xample.monktre(23516): Accessing hidden field Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;->descriptor:I (light greylist, JNI)
W/xample.monktre(23516): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V (light greylist, reflection)
W/xample.monktre(23516): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard;->getThreadPolicy()Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy; (light greylist, linking)
W/xample.monktre(23516): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy;->onNetwork()V (light greylist, linking)
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you update flutter to say 1.17.3?

Comment: No i am still running 1.17.0

Comment: Are you using email and password logins?

Comment: @GunJack Yes I am

Comment: Same issue here. Did you get it figured out?

Comment: Not yet, I am trying to fix it.